# Having trouble converting a Python script to .exe with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller

I was unable to download py2exe after many attempts. On my second attempt I was able to install Pyinstaller. It does make an executable out of my script (which has nothing in it but print('hello')). The executable does not work, though. When I run it, it gives the error: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8

There are some people who have had similar or the same problems, but the answers were unclear or really technical. I'm a beginner at Python and don't know any of its 'deep inner workings', so a clear beginner's answer would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you install with pip or did you do it manually?

Comment: I went into the Anaconda Prompt and put: conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller

Comment: Can you compile in debug mode. like so, pyinstaller -d yourfile.py? Then run the file from the console. I think there is a module dependency error outside of pyinstaller that is causing this. Some people [posted a bug](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3146) earlier about this issue, and it ended up being just that.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, pyinstaller -d garbage.py, it made a build folder and dist folder with executables garbage.exe. However, they closed as soon as they opened, and it seems that those executables are not the actual garbage.exe that I am trying to make, since they are printing a bunch of lines like 'Looking for dynamic libraries', 'looking for eggs' etc.

Comment: Hi, just letting you know that I was able to solve my overall problem by doing pip install cx_freeze, and then following the procedure at this link: https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-python-scripts-exe-executables/    thanks for your help and concern!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out. pip is a great tool.